# jQuery Tools Tooltips does not work simply by an outer div having position: relative?

Tags: javascript, tooltip, jquery-tools

A third party jQuery tooltip is [jQuery Tools Tooltips: ToolTips Done Right](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html).  Can it be breaking just by having an outer div with `position: relative`?

This one works:
http://www.topics2look.com/code-examples/jquery-tools-tooltip-bug/this-works.html

Just adding a `position: relative` to the outer div (the one with blue border), and the tooltip gets massively misplaced (by whatever amount the header div pushes down): http://www.topics2look.com/code-examples/jquery-tools-tooltip-bug/with-relative-position-it-does-not-work.html

The quality of 3rd party open-source code.

Does any jQuery guru have a fix quickly?  The requirement is that the outer div must have `position: relative` or `position: absolute` for one reason or another.  I think the reason it is breaking is that jQuery Tools Tooltip uses `position: absolute` to position the tooltip, but without knowing that the `absolute` is actually relative to the "nearest ancestor that is **positioned**", as the CSS spec says.  So it breaks, by just a simple case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the [`relative` property](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html#configuration) (third from the bottom).

```
$('#main-content').tooltip({
    bounce: false,
    relative: true, // <-- Adding this should sort you out
    slideOffset: 5,
    effect: 'slide',
    direction: 'down',
    slideInSpeed: 300,
    slideOutSpeed: 200,
    position: 'bottom center'
});
```

Comment: you nailed this one, although I wonder why the one relative to the document cannot be made to work well, and also why the `relative: true` is not the default, because it is more accurate.

Comment: i still have this problem, when my container has also overflow: scroll. The tooltips are misplaced when you scroll down and open a tooltip. Does someone maybe know the solution to this?

Comment: I'm not sure. To be honest, I think the way jQuery Tools does tool-tips  is wonk. They should just re-inject the extra tool-tip markup just before the closing `</body>` tag so that `position:relative` doesn't affect it's positioning.